# how to call an xml field into html

Tags: javascript, xml, web-services

I have the url to web service which returns some xml data. I need to load this xml data and include only the value of the date tag on my site. How can this be done?

this is the url which returns xml:

http://www.islamicfinder.org/prayer_service.php?country=usa&city=new_york&state=NY&zipcode=10006&latitude=40.7092&longitude=-74.0128&timezone=-5&HanfiShafi=1&pmethod=5&fajrTwilight1=10&fajrTwilight2=10&ishaTwilight=10&ishaInterval=30&dhuhrInterval=1&maghribInterval=1&dayLight=1&simpleFormat=xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<prayer>
    <fajr>4:12</fajr>
    <sunrise>5:43</sunrise>
    <dhuhr>1:03</dhuhr>
    <asr>5:00</asr>
    <maghrib>8:22</maghrib>
    <isha>9:54</isha>
    <date>July 21, 2012</date>
    <hijri>2 Ramadan 1433</hijri>
    <city>New York</city>
    <country>Usa</country>
    <website>www.IslamicFinder.org</website>
</prayer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using PHP's [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5094)

```
<?php
  $url = 'http://www.islamicfinder.org/prayer_service.php?country=usa&city=new_york&state=NY&zipcode=10006&latitude=40.7092&longitude=-74.0128&timezone=-5&HanfiShafi=1&pmethod=5&fajrTwilight1=10&fajrTwilight2=10&ishaTwilight=10&ishaInterval=30&dhuhrInterval=1&maghribInterval=1&dayLight=1&simpleFormat=xml';
  $result = new SimpleXMLElement($url, NULL, true);
  echo $result->date;
?>
```

The NULL means we're not passing any options. True means we're getting the data from a URL. Check out the arguments [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php).

Comment: you need to add `true` as the second parameter to the constructor if you want to load a URL like that. Also it doesnt say specifically that he is working with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I m getting date using php i hope it works for you..

```
<?php

/**
 * @author Waqas Ahmed
 */

$url = "http://www.islamicfinder.org/prayer_service.php?country=usa&city=new_york&state=NY&zipcode=10006&latitude=40.7092&longitude=-74.0128&timezone=-5&HanfiShafi=1&pmethod=5&fajrTwilight1=10&fajrTwilight2=10&ishaTwilight=10&ishaInterval=30&dhuhrInterval=1&maghribInterval=1&dayLight=1&simpleFormat=xml";
$xmlData = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xmlData);
$dates = $doc->getElementsByTagName('date');
foreach($dates as $date)
{
    echo " Date : ".$date->nodeValue;
}

?>
```